# How can Teams Desktop clear cache automatically, after each use and quitting?

Tags: microsoft-teams

How can Teams [clear cache as outlined by Veejay RC](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/clear-cache/0810ce4f-af14-4269-b01f-adc89a0af4c4) AUTOMATICALLY after each time I quit Teams or shut down my desktop?

> To clear your Teams desktop app cache:
> 1. Sign out on Teams > Quit Microsoft Teams by right clicking the icon and select Quit.
> 2. On your keyboard, Hold Windows key and Press R
> 3. Cut and paste %appdata%\Microsoft\Teams in the RUN then OK.
> 4. Delete the contents of the entire folder.
> 5. Restart Device > Restart Microsoft Teams > Sign In.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to automate the entire process? Say a batch file or some sort of script to perform all of those actions for you, with 1 click/button press/icon?

Comment: As said by @spikey_richie it is possible using some sort of script. However, Deleting teams cache back and again isn't very helpful — Teams will download that data again when you open teams and this will increase the loading time of teams. Plus, You'll need to sign in again. So, I would suggest you **NOT** to do this; consider the space Teams cache is occupying as an investment which saves time and improves efficiency and practicality.

Comment: And, I just saw your other question, too. You must wait, you'll be helped with your problem there — clearing cache every time isn't that practical solution.